# Can JAXB generate a generic class?

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc

Can I get JAXB 2.0 XJC compiler to generate a generic class for me?

Something as simple as:-

```
public class Shape<T> {
    T myShape;
    // getter / setter
}
```

I see references for this in the spec but am not sure I'm reading it right. I always get Object references.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826736/jaxb-marshalling-and-generics

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, no. However, it is quite [easy to write an XJC plugin](https://jaxb.dev.java.net/plugin.html) to get fine control over what code is generated.