# Best Practice for Serialize/Deserialize from Java to XML

Tags: java, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

What is the most appropriate way to serialize Java Classes to XML?
I tried JAXB, but it has issues with Interfaces and Generics. What solution is least intrusive but scalable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've always had positive experiences with XStream:

http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html#to-xml

As you can see, it's simple to use.

I haven't actually used XStream with Generics (I've only ever used it for simple JavaBean type classes), but Google seems to suggest it handles them without problems. e.g. http://techo-ecco.com/blog/xstream-spring-ws-oxm-and-generics/

Comment: n.b. that blog link leads on to talk about using Spring to simplify the outputted xml, but the first xml snippet indicates that plain-old XStream handles the Generic LinkedList nicely

Comment: The tutorial itself uses a List<T> so it seems to be working. Therefore the /must have standard constructor/ is fair tradeoff.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to overcome the issues with interfaces and generics you have with JAXB.

[JAXB Marshalling and Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826736/jaxb-marshalling-and-generics)

[java.util.List is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298733/java-util-list-is-an-interface-and-jaxb-cant-handle-interfaces)

Comment: I already read those but find the sollutions wont fit, it does not scale to build Adapters for every Class using generics.
Transformation to/from Arrays would be OK - if JAXB would do it transparently and without my help.