# JAXB and collections containing generics

Tags: java, generics, jaxb

We have the JAXB/Java code below.  This worked fine until we changed `List<JQGridTO> rows` to `List<? extends JQGridTO> rows`.

When we made that change we get this error:

> Constructor threw exception; nested
>   exception is com.sun.
>   xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of
>   IllegalAnnotationExceptions Property
>   rows appears in @XmlType.propOrder,
>   but no such property exists. Maybe you
>   meant records?
>           this problem is related to the following location:
>                   at com.me.ui.service.JQGridJsonRoot

Why do we get this error?  Can't you use Generics as we did (ie: specifing `? extends XXX`)?

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "records",
        "page",
        "total",
        "rows"
})
public class JQGridJsonRoot {
    int total; //total pages for the query
    int page; //current page of the query
    int records; //total number of records for the query
    List<? extends JQGridTO> rows
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this SO post. I think it has what you need: [JAXB Marshalling and Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826736/jaxb-marshalling-and-generics)